# DataTable: hide and not remove rows

Tags: forms, datatable, hide

When I use DataTable in client-side mode (on an existing table), only the displayed rows are inserted in the DOM (I use the paginator). This is annoying as my table displays a form, so the hidden rows aren't sent when I submit the form.

Is it possible to only hide the rows and not remove them from DOM ?

Comment: Please post your code too; "_my table displays a form_" is a very broad statement.

Comment: did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it yet but the documentation says there is an API, from which we can get the whole form content and even modify the form - even rows that aren't displayed  - so that answers my question.